# Need help to reduce spaces between banner & content on weebly site

Tags: html, css, reduce, weebly

I am using weebly templates and working with the CSS files. Here is my site www.zxentest.weebly.com

I need help in reducing gap space below the yellow banner to the faint line at the sides, and reduce the space above the main text..

Could anyone help with this? I have tried to edit the css file and put 0px on most of the margins and padding that surrounds the main body and banner, but to no avail. help greatly appreciated! thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re reading the question what you actually want to do is remove `margin-bottom` and decrease the size of your `padding-bottom` to however close you want the text to be to your banner.

Comment: hi thre, thanks for the input, however that didnt help solve the gap spaces..

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I misread your question I thought we were moving the banner away from the top. recall what I just said. in that same class on css remove your margin-bottom, and then decrease your padding-bottom to your taste. that should achieve what you actually wanted. editing my answer now.

Comment: YES! THANK YOU!! that did the trick! i guess i was focused on adjusting top padding n margin of the body which didnt work. but bottom margin and bottom padding worked great!!

Comment: You're very welcome, enjoy!